# PM system - previewing previous PMs

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PM system where I'd like to have the previous sent PMs for one conversation, listed above the last received PM. But my question is: how do I go about setting up such a table in a database? I toyed for a while about using an id for each specific conversation, but what would the source for that id be? I can't use auto increment (it seems), because I'm using it for the primary "id" column.

Or maybe there's a completely different way I can experiment with the already available columns (id, from, to, subject, message, sent, read, deleted); but how? Please help a lost man out.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `origin_id` column to your table that contains the `id` of the root/original message, or `NULL` if it's a new discussion (root).

Then you can get the root messages by filtering those than have `origin_id = NULL` and then group by `origin_id` to get the message thread.

Comment: I think you meant, "id of the original message". If you use origin_id to point to the previous message, you'd have to make a database call for every message in the thread to get the next one in sequence. Having all threaded messages pointing to the origin lets you group by the origin_id as you suggested, and order by date.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have got it partly solved...
I used another table containing the one column which holds the subject of the PM. I also have a new column in the regular "pms" table that holds the same ID to be able to join the tables together.

However, when I select all the PMs to show them in the inbox, I have not found a way to group the conversations in order by if they're read or not. I'm currently using this SQL query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `pms` 
    JOIN `pm_conversations` ON (pms.ConvID = pm_conversations.ID) 
   WHERE pms.To='username' 
GROUP BY pm_conversations.ID 
ORDER BY pms.ID
```

I came up with this:

```
   SELECT MAX(pms.ID) as pmIDS,
          pms.*,
          pm_conversations.* 
    FROM `pms` 
    JOIN `pm_conversations` ON (pms.ConvID = pm_conversations.ID)
   WHERE `To`='".$UserActive."' 
GROUP BY pm_conversations.ID 
ORDER BY pmIDS DESC
```